# Script for creating dictionary from coordinates?

Tags: python, dictionary, geocode

New here, and this is my first post.

I have a python script that I am working on, and the scripts main purpose is to take a list of cities from a .txt file on my computer, and have the script spit out a dictionary where the keys are the city names and the values are the locations as point objects. Also, I have to take this dictionary of points objects and the new file location and write the new values to a text file with the data in rows (city names next to the coordinates in the dictionary).

I have literally spend about 30 hours on this over the past 2 weeks, and still have had no luck getting this to work fully. Right now, the city names and the coordinates will print out in the python shell, and just the city names will print out to the text file, but I cannot get the city names and the coordinates combined in one dictionary to print out into one text file.

I am using a python module called locations.pyc and this module has the purpose of going out onto the internet, to a Google server, and then bringing in the coordinates associated with the city names in the list. The cities are all in Alaska..

This is the script so far.

```
import location         # calls the location module in file


def getFileList(path):
    f = open(path, "r")
    f.readline()
    fileList = []       # removes column header
    for line in f:
        fileList.append(line.strip())
    f.close()
    return fileList


class Point:
    def __init__(self, x = 0, y = 0):
        self.x = float(x)
        self.y = float(y)


def makeCitiesDict(citiesList):
    CitiesDict = dict()
    for city in citiesList:
        loc = location.getaddresslocation(city)
        x = loc[0]
        y = loc[1]
        CitiesDict[city] = Point(x, y)

    return CitiesDict

def writeDictFile(aDict):
    txt_file = open(r"Alaska.txt",'w')
    txt_file.writelines(myCitiesDict)
    txt_file.close()

myCities = getFileList(r"cities_Small.txt")

myCitiesDict = makeCitiesDict(myCities)
writeDictFile("myCitiesDict\n")   

print myCitiesDict

for key in myCitiesDict:
    point = myCitiesDict[key]
    print point.x,point.y
```

Here is the link to the locations.pyc module that is used to run the script. 
[location.pyc](https://github.com/mapossum/spa/blob/master/week4/location.pyc)

Answer (score 1):

Your current version of `writeDictFile` will fail with an error when you pass it your current big dictionary:

> TypeError: writelines() argument must be a sequence of strings

To solve it, you could do several things:

1. Iterate manually over the key-value pairs in the dict and write them manually to the file:

   ```
   def write_to_file(d):
       with open(outputfile, 'w') as f:
           for key, value in d.items():
               f.write('{}\t{}\t{}\n'.format(key, value.x, value.y))
   ```
2. Use the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) to do the work for you. However, in that case you'll want to convert your single big dictionary to a list of small dictionaries:

   ```
   def makeCitiesDict(citiesList):
       citylist = []
       for city in citiesList:
           loc = location.getaddresslocation(city)
           x = loc[0]
           y = loc[1]
           citylist.append({'cityname': city, 'lon': x, 'lat': y})
       return citylist


   def writeDictFile(biglist):
       with open(outputfile, 'w') as f:
           dw = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=('lon', 'lat', 'cityname'), delimiter='\t')
           dw.writerows(biglist)
   ```

By the way, python coding conventions suggest not to use camelCase for function names. Have a look at [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) if you're interested.

Comment: I tried importing the csv module but it gives me an error saying 'true' is not defined, and I think this is because the location module is not compatible with the csv module. I did find a way to combine the city name with the coordinates in the shell, but it still will not print both in the output text file. It just still prints the city names only, in one single row, in the text file. How would I specifically combine the coordinates with the names in the writeDictFile function?

Comment: I just now added the function call "writeDictFile" to the script above, somehow I forgot it earlier, but it works with that function call.

Comment: @EDM, I frown when I read that a third-party module would have compatibility issues with such a simple module from the standard library. I suggest looking for an alternative then (e.g. [geopy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geopy/1.7.1)). But maybe the problem isn't there, it's hard to tell without a complete stacktrace. Anyway, I don't understand your first comment: did you try the `write_to_file` function shown above in the first example? It should be a drop-in replacement for `writeDictFile(myCitiesDict)`, as long as you define the variable `outputfile` in either the local or global scope.